# hello world example struts Sequence diagram

Tags: java, servlets, struts, sequence-diagram

I have a specific doubt.

In the example,[hello world example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html)
[image]

I have drawn a sequence diagram. I Have to represent the role tomcat is playing in the diagram. Is this the right way to represent? What does the struts-config.xml file do in this diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need of `web.xml` before the `web server layer` in your sequence diagram.In fact, the `web server` or `servlet engine` is the one that parses the web.xml and loads the `ActionServlet` when you deploy the application.So in this case, web.xml is not coming into the picture.All the request will be processed by your `Action class`.That you can include here.

`Struts-Config` will be loaded by your `ActionServlet` when you deploy the application.Your web server is comprised of

1.`web.xml` which will load the `action servlet` which in turn load all action classes during deploying the application.

2.when a user makes a request, this `action class` is the one that is serving your request.
   You can represent the action class here.

Comment: Ok. But what about the struts-config.xml? I know that it hold all the mapping, but how can I represent it in the diagram?

Comment: Struts-config will be loaded by your ActionServlet when you deploy the application